# CloudStorageAccount not working. Unable to create a cloud storage account

Tags: c#, azure

I used this :

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
```

and error came up:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So I used:

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account_name;AccountKey=account_key");
```

But the error still persists.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Its .NET 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to build a WP 8.1 Application. As of now WP 8.1 is not supported in the azure storage 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage

You can try to use the azure management api instead.